# Dynamic Partitioning + CREATE AS on HIVE

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive, database-partitioning

I'm trying to create a new table from another table with `CREATE AS` and dynamic Partitioning on HiveCLI. I'm learning from Hive official wiki where there is this example:

```
 CREATE TABLE T (key int, value string) 
 PARTITIONED BY (ds string, hr int) AS
 SELECT key, value, ds, hr+1 hr1 
   FROM srcpart 
   WHERE ds is not null 
   And hr>10;
```

But I received this error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10065]:
>
> CREATE TABLE AS SELECT command cannot specify the list of columns for the target table

Source: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions#DynamicPartitions-Syntax

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you already know the full schema of the target table, try creating it first and the populating it with a LOAD DATA command:

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

CREATE TABLE T (key int, value string) 
PARTITIONED BY (ds string, hr int);

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T PARTITION(ds, hr) 
SELECT key, value, ds, hr+1 AS hr 
   FROM srcpart 
   WHERE ds is not null 
   And hr>10;
```

Note: the set command is needed since you are performing a full dynamic partition insert.

Comment: Yes I did it,  it seems the best and unique solution

Comment: Whats the best way to do this if you *don't* already know the full schema of the target table?  Is it possible to generate a partitioned table from an un-partitioned one using only hive queries?

Comment: `show create table <schema.table>;` @Noah Will give you the schema, you should code out the schema and be explicit in listing columns in BOTH DDL and SELECT statements. Understand more work, but lazy dev practices not to.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

CREATE TABLE T (key int, value string) 
PARTITIONED BY (ds string, hr int);

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T PARTITION(ds, hr) 
SELECT key, value, ds, hr+1 AS hr 
FROM srcpart 
WHERE ds is not null 
      And hr>10;
```

In the above code, instead of the `Create` statement use: `CREATE TABLE T like srcpart`;

In case the partitioning is similar.