# Create a hive table like another but partitioned by key

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, partitioning

In Hive, I would like to create a table with another table's columns but partition it with one of them. Is that possible? Ideally, I would like to perform something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists new_table
LIKE old_table
PARTITIONED BY (col1 int)
```

Right now this doesn't run as it seems that I can't add `partitioned by` after using a `like` clause. I'm looking for alternatives as I'm trying to write a generalized function without having to specifically parse or hard code the schema.

Comment: use `alter table ...` to add partition after creating the table.

Comment: You could use a CTAS function instead, but in that case, you will need the schema

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Partitioning + CREATE AS on HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477855/dynamic-partitioning-create-as-on-hive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a way to do it in one query in a general way. I ended up reading the schema using `describe old_table`, creating the table with said schema and partition with key. Afterwards, I loop through all my partition values and `alter table` with necessary partitions.